# angular2 with sweetalert2 that prompts then gives a response

Tags: angular, sweetalert

I have an mvc with angular2 website.  I want to give a sweetalert2 message asking the user to confirm they want to update their data.  If they confirm I need the sweetalert2 box to show the loading/waiting while the service calls the server to update the data.  The server call responseds with a bool to let the user know if the update was successful or not, which I want to display with a sweetalert2 success or error dialog.  Below is my code, but my console gives me the error: 'Unhandled Promise rejection: Unexpected token <...'.  This is my first angular2 app and first time using sweetalert2 and can't seem to find an example without an ajax call.

My service originally returned an Observable and my component had the .subscribe(...), but I changed it to a boolean thinking it would work in the Promise.  The service's postaction calls my ServiceAdapter class that does the http.post.

**UPDATE**:

I figured out how to get it to show the loading while the preConfirm runs, but it can't seem to call service.  I simulate the service call taking time with the settimeout(...,5000).  After the 5 secs I get the console error: Cannot read property 'updateStuff' of undefined.  How do I get it to call this._myService?

**UPDATE 2 / Answer**

Updating this in case anyone else needs the same workflow.
I did figure out how to get the workflow I needed.  This gives an initial message, then shows the loading screen while waiting for the service response.  It then gives me a success or error message based on the service's response.

Code updated to latest version.

```
inside my component:
constructor(private _myService: MyService){}


 onUpdateClick(){
     swal({
         title: 'Update?',
         text: 'Are you sure you want to update stuff?',
         showCancelButton: true,
         allowOutsideClick: false,
         showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
         preConfirm: function () {
             return new Promise(() => {
                     (this._myService.updateStuff(this.selectedId, this.updateObject)
                         .subscribe((result: boolean) => {


                             if (result.length > 0) {
                                 console.log("it worked with msg: " + result);
                                 swal('It worked', 'stuff was updated', 'success');
                             }
                             else {
                                 console.log("it died with error: " + result);
                                 swal('It failed', 'nothing updated', 'error');
                             }
                         }
                    ))
                 });
         }
     }).catch(function (arg) {
         console.log("exited b/c " + arg);
         swal({
             type: 'error',
             title: 'failure',
             html: 'some error response'
         })
     });
 }


my service:
updateStuff(selectedId number, updateObject: UpdateObject): Observable<boolean>{
    var params: Object = { selectedId: selectedId, updateObject: updateObject };
    var result = this.postaction(params, 'myControllerPath' )
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score -1):

For you to have access to the service, you should capture this before the call to swal in a variable, for example, _this = this